# SQL - Order of records returned in join by default

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, table **A** and **B**
Relationship is **1:n**

There is only **one** record in table A and **many** records in table B

I am doing an **inner join**

What would be the order of product records returned?
I mean, what is the order of records in table B?

Would it be as if I just have queried SELECT * FROM B? (If so, what is the default order of records returned with this query?)
Is there any official documentation about it? I don't want to guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"What would be the order of product records returned?"* it would be in what ever order you defined in your `ORDER BY` clause. If you didn't define one, it would be completely arbitrary.

Comment: There is indeed no ORDER BY. Do you have an official documentation about that?

Comment: If there's no order by then it's just whatever order the query hits the records in - if you've got a clustered index on the primary key, then it'll probably be whatever order that defines. Otherwise it's just whatever arbitrary order the query thinks will be quickest (which can be different each time you run it). If you want a predictable order, assign one.

Comment: Do you guys have an official doc about it?

Comment: Even if you have a `CLSUTERED INDEX` the rows you get back may well not follow that order @AndrewCorrigan ; if it does it's more luck. It not being the same especially comes true if you have a partitioned table, shared locks, parallelism, and that doesn't even start on `JOINS` or `WHERE`s, etc, etc. Don't forget, Richard98PL, tables in SQL are inherently unordered. If you just ask for "All the data from a table" then the RDBMS will, effectively, just return the rows in the order it finds them in; which can literally be any arbitrary order.

Comment: Of course @Larnu - "probably" probably wasn't the best term.

Comment: I think the lack of any docs stating that it *should* be in a defined order is more telling: it's simply unspecified